# How do implement a variable similar to Spark's Accumulators in Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam

I am currently using Apache Beam 2.29.0 in Spark. My pipeline consumes data from Kafka for which I have a custom KafkaConsumer that Beam creates thru a call to a ConsumerFactoryFn. I need to share a piece of persistent data for the duration of the run among the custom Kafka consumers. This would have been very simple in Spark I would have create an Accumulator variable that all the executors will have access to as well as the driver.
Since Beam is designed to run in multiple platforms Spark, Flink, Google Dataflow it does not provide this functionality. Does anybody knows a way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Side Inputs should work. You can read about the Side Inputs [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs). A side input is an additional input that your DoFn can access each time it processes an element in the input PCollection.

[Here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/filter/#example-4-filtering-with-side-inputs-as-singletons) Is an example of how to use it.